# I need my dropbox not to change after refreshing or opening the page

Tags: html, select, dropdown

I have a dropdown selection of two options. In stock or out of stock. I need the dropdown to stay the same as what was selected after someone leaves the page. Im sorry if there is a simple fix to this. I am new to web development and cant seem to get it to work. Everytime I refresh the page it goes to the default.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

HTML alone is great if you want to give everyone the same exact page.  But in order to do what you want to do, you will most likely need Javascript. If you haven't used Javascript before, [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript) can teach you how to use it.

You will need 3 parts if you go with this method.

Part 1. Store a cookie with the drop-down selected value.

```
<script>
    function storeCookie(name, value){
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";
    }
```

Part 2. Check if a cookie already exists, and if it does then get the value that should be selected in your drop-down.

```
    function cookieExists(name){
        return -1 != document.cookie.indexOf( name + "=");
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Part 3. Tie it all together.

```
    function main(){
        var cookieName = "yourcookiename";
        if(cookieExists(cookieName){
            var value = getCookie(cookiename);

            //This is where you set the value in your drop-down with Javascript

        }
    }
</script>
```

Furthermore, you should call `storeCookie("yourcookiename", "yourcookievalue")` when the webpage knows what value should stay selected, and call `main()` when the page loads.